# Close SelectField menu with multiple=true

Tags: reactjs, input, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I am trying to close from the outside a SelectField. The idea is that I have a multiple selectField (which doesn't close on change by definition) with a "Clear All" item in the drop down menu that deselects all items on click.

The code I have is similar to this:

```
class MultiSelect extends Component {
    state = {values: []}
    clear = () => {
        this.setState({values: []});
        // FixMe: close the DropDownMenu here. 
    };
    handleChange = (e,i,v) => {
        this.setState({values: v});
    };
    render() {
        const {title, choices, style} = this.props;
        const {values} = this.state
        return <div style={{...style}}>
            <SelectField
                floatingLabelText={title}
                multiple
                value={values}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
                <MenuItem value={null} primaryText="Clear All" onTouchTap={this.clear}/>
                <Divider/>
                {choices.map((d,i) =>
                    <MenuItem key={i} value={d} primaryText={d} checked={values.includes(d)}/>
                )}
            </SelectField>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The best way of achieving this would be to call the `DropDownMenu.close()` function. Using the newly introduced `dropDownMenuProps` prop of `SelectField` I thought I could do this, however the function apparently gets overwritten in `DropDownMenu`.

So, is there another way to achieve this or should I implement this component from scratch using the `DropDownMenu` directly?